# PHP mySQL code not posting to database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am working on having data taken from a form submit to a database, however, whenever I submit there are no errors yet my data never appears in my database. Can anyone help me with some information on what I might have done incorrectly?  I am using phpMyAdmin to view my table.
Thank You,
Stephen

```
<?php

$user= $_POST["txtUser"];
$fName= $_POST["txtFname"];
$lName= $_POST["txtLname"];
$email= $_POST["txtEmail"];
$date= date("r"); 



$dbh=mysql_connect('webdb.uvm.edu','swakita','MYPASSWORD');

if (!$dbh)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("SWAKITA", $dbh);

if (isset($_POST['butSubmit'])) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblWhere (pk_Username, fldFirstName, fldLastName, fldAdminLevel, fldTotalPosts, fldDateJoined, fldEmail) VALUES (" . $user . "," . $fName .     "," . $Lname . ", '4', '0', $date, $email)");
mysql_close();
print $user;
}
?>
```

**EDIT**
This error is thrown:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Here is my code currently:

```
<?php

$user= $_POST["txtUser"];
$fName= $_POST["txtFname"];
$lName= $_POST["txtLname"];
$email= $_POST["txtEmail"];
$date= date("r"); 



$dbh=mysql_connect('webdb.uvm.edu','swakita','efaemaey');

if (!$dbh)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db('SWAKITA', $dbh);

if (isset($_POST['butSubmit'])) {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblWhere (pk_Username, fldFirstName, fldLastName, fldAdminLevel, fldTotalPosts, fldDateJoined, fldEmail) VALUES (' mysql_real_escape_string($user)', 'mysql_real_escape_string($fName)', 'mysql_real_escape_string($Lname)', '4', '0', 'mysql_real_escape_string($date)', 'mysql_real_escape_string($email)'");
if (mysql_errno()) {
echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
}
mysql_close();
print $user;
}
?>
```

**EDIT EDIT**
I was missing a parentheses after 'mysql_real_escape_string($email)' but now it is posting "mysql_real_escape_string(Example First Name)" instead of just the value. What did I do wrong with my parentheses now?

Comment: For a moment I was scared that you didn't hide your password...

Comment: Haha, nope, even though I'm half asleep I did manage to remember to do that.

Comment: Add `or die(mysql_error()` after each MySQL statement, so we can see what's happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use your fields coming from the POST request directly in the query, you're vulnerable of [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), escape them first.

```
$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["txtUser"]);
...
```

To see the problem, check the result of mysql_query

```
mysql_query(...);
if (mysql_errno()) {
    echo $sql . "<br/>\n" . mysql_error();
}
```

I think the problem is that you're not putting quotes around fields like user.

```
VALUES (" . $user . "," . $fName . ", ...
```

should be:

```
VALUES ('" . $user . "', '" . $fName . "', ...
```

or simpler:

```
VALUES('$user', '$fName', ...
```

If you quote your string with double quotes ", you can use $variable inside the string and they will get evaluated, while if you use a string delimited with single quotes ', it will literally print $variable.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, I'll be sure to escape from now on, I'm new to this

Comment: it's mysql_real_escape_string() in case you try this and it doesn't work.

Comment: still having an issue, trying your last suggestion with  quotes, right now I have

Comment: did you add the error checking after the query, does it print any error?

Comment: I solved my initial problem, it is posting now but it posts as mysql_real_escape_string(example) as opposed to just "example'? Can you help me with this?

Comment: @Wakeeta, use the mysql_real_escape string where you get your values (`$user= $_POST["txtUser"];`), not in the query string or the function instead of getting executed will just get inside the string as a literal.

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblWhere (pk_Username, fldFirstName, fldLastName, fldAdminLevel, fldTotalPosts, fldDateJoined, fldEmail) VALUES ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($fName) .     "','" . mysql_real_escape_string($Lname) . "', '4', '0', '".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email')."'");
```

You need to wrap strings with ' single quotes. and please escape properly or get hacked. [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) will help.

Comment: thank you very much, i will start using escapes from now on, I'm new to php/mysql